# Applying a global style/event to a MahApps.Metro textbox disables the watermark

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am developing a windows app and utilizing the `MahApps.Metro` from NuGet, version 1.5.0. I ran into an issue where setting global properties causes the textbox to disappear. Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Create new WPF application
2. Install `MahApps.Metro` from NuGet (console or command line)
3. Configure App.xaml and MainWindow.xaml (and .cs) to handle `MahApps.Metro`
4. Create a simple textbox with the watermark property (`Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="<watermark here>"` is default).
5. Run application. Watermark shows up as intended.

Here is the .xaml for my sample app. Notice I changed `Controls` to `mah` (doesn't matter; I tried `Controls` and `mah` no difference was made):

```
<mah:MetroWindow x:Class="MahAppsTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MahAppsTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox mah:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Test" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</mah:MetroWindow>
```

Now if I go into the App.xaml file and add the following:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
</Style>
```

Remove the property from the textbox (or keep it there, doesn't matter) then run the application, the watermark is now gone. It does not matter if it is a `<Setter>` or `<EventSetter>`. The watermark shows up in the IDE, though.

I saw on their GitHub repo under issues that some people had this solved by adding `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"` to the `<Style>` tag, but that all seems to be applied in the `MainWindow.xaml` or equivalent rather than globally in the `App.xaml`file.

**EDIT:** I also tried adding the `{x:Type ...}` argument before making the post.

Has anyone experienced this and know a fix?

I am running MahApps.Metro v1.5.0 in Visual Studio 2017 programming in C# v4.6.1 (according to target framework) on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to base your style on the MahApps style.  As written, you will extend the *default* `TextBox` style (which has no watermark).  Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
</Style>
```

I *think* that will work.  You'll need to make sure the MahApps styles are in scope at the point where you declare that resource, though.  If you're pulling the MahApps resources into your `App.xaml`, then just make sure this style is declared further down.

If for some reason this doesn't work, try replacing `MetroTextBox` with `{x:Type TextBox}`.  It [*looks* like](http://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/c26b33d114aec64d98afd4f729b28838583d8ed9/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.TextBox.xaml) `MetroTextBox` is the style name, but I could be wrong.

I'm not sure what you mean by this, though:

> Configure App.xaml and MainWindow.xaml (and .cs) to handle MahApps.Metro

If you mean that you are importing the MahApps.Metro style resources into both your `App.xaml` *and* `MainWindow.xaml`, then that is unnecessary.  Putting them in `App.xaml` ought to suffice.

---

This is what I tried, and it worked for me:

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>

      <!-- MahApps.Metro Resource Imports -->
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

      <!-- Global TextBox Style Override -->
      <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Crimson" />
      </Style>

    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<m:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
               xmlns:m="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
               SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
  <TextBox m:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Test" Width="300" />
</m:MetroWindow>
```

**Result:**

[image: Screenshot of TextBox with Global Style Applied]

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work for me; IntelliSense says "`Resource StandardTextBox not found`". I did add `xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"` to the top of `App.xaml`. That part you highlighted was making sure you changed `MainWindow : Window` to `MainWindow : MetroWindow` in the code-behind and the xaml.

Comment: `{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}` also does not bring the watermark back.

Comment: I should note, though, that I did try the `{x:Type TextBox}}` before posting this. Omitting the `BasedOn` argument did not change the situation. I'll edit the post for clarification.

Comment: Presumably, the MahApps styles are getting imported into either your application-level resources or window-level resources _somehow_.  I had thought this had to be done manually via `Resources.MergedDictionaries`.  Are you not doing something like that?

Comment: I do have the merged dictionaries in `App.xaml` per http://mahapps.com/guides/quick-start.html under "Using Built-In Styles" heading. My `<Style>` tag is below the `Resources.MergedDictionaries` section in the file.

Comment: Whoops, I was looking at the wrong file on GitHub.  The base style name is `MetroTextBox`, not `StandardTextBox`.  Also, keep in mind you'll need to remove the explicit `Margin` on your text box, because a local value will always take priority over style setters.

Comment: Alright I will test that out when I get back to the office and see if that remedies the issue!

Comment: Perfect; `MetroTextBox` was indeed all that was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this issue also without MahApps and became the same result (a base Style in a ResourceDictionary which is referenced in App.xaml).

After some trials and errors I found a solution which works with and without MahApps.

The trick is defining a base style with a key in a extra ResourceDictionary (can be also a separate one) and use this to define a base style which is now used everywhere.

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication16.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <!-- Accent and AppTheme setting -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />

                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style x:Key="BaseTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Goldenrod" />
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
                        <Setter Property="controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton" Value="True" />
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseTextBoxStyle}" />

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Sample**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication16.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

        <TextBox Margin="10" Text="Test" MinWidth="200" />

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Interesting solution; I will try this as well. If you see the accepted answer, the style had to be based on `MetroTextBox`.