How can I change the watermark "color?
Hers's my basic setting for a TextBox:
<TextBox x:Name="NomeRapporto"
         Text="{Binding NomeRapporto}"
         controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Nome Rapporto"
         controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermar="True" />

which render this way empty:

And when I insert a text manually via the interface, it appears like this:

As you can see, when focused, there is that "blue" color. How can I change to (for example) red?
Thanks

WPF does not have watermark for TextBox out of the box, so you should specify what you are using to add this behavior, so it would be possible to reply properly to your question

@Demon as stated in tags, I'm using mahapps.metro

does this help: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/11395

@RandRandom where should I add it? There is no Key?

if you are looking into mashapp, then check this way to apply style https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216190/applying-a-global-style-event-to-a-mahapps-metro-textbox-disables-the-watermark

Define a custom MahApps.Brushes.TextBlock.FloatingMessage resource:
<TextBox x:Name="NomeRapporto"
         Text="{Binding NomeRapporto}"
         controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Nome Rapporto"
         controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True">
    <TextBox.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MahApps.Brushes.TextBlock.FloatingMessage" Color="Red" />
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>

